# I have developed a SQL query, and I got an error "Divide by zero error encountered."

Tags: sql, null, divide-by-zero

```
SELECT 
    TheDate, 00 AS ReportID, 
    (SELECT SiteID FROM LocalVariables) AS SiteID,      
    (SELECT COUNT(COALESCE([ReviewID], 0)) AS Expr1 
     FROM [RAAudits]  
     WHERE (CAST([DateCompleted] AS date) = DateExtended.TheDate) 
    AND pass = 1) * 100 /
          (SELECT COUNT(COALESCE([ReviewID], 0)) AS Expr2 
           FROM [RAAudits]  
           WHERE (CAST([DateCompleted] AS date) = DateExtended.TheDate)) AS DataValue
FROM   
    DateExtended  
WHERE  
    TheDate BETWEEN (SELECT ServiceStartDate FROM LocalVariables) 
                AND GETDATE() -1
```

Comment: show your  example data in #TEMP table and we can help with query

Comment: There is too much implied and hidden information here.  For example, I'm inferring that `localVariables` only has one row, and that `[DateCompleted]` comes from the `DateExtended` table, but in neither case can I be sure.  You should give enough example data that we can replicate what you want to do, which is all explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `avg()` instead.  Assuming `pass` only takes on the values `0` and `1`:

```
SELECT TheDate, 00 As ReportID,
       (SELECT SiteID from LocalVariables) as SiteID,      
       (SELECT AVG(pass * 100.0)
        FROM [RAAudits]  
        WHERE cast([DateCompleted] as date) = DateExtended.theDate
       )
FROM DateExtended  
WHERE TheDate BETWEEN (SELECT ServiceStartDate from LocalVariables) AND GETDATE() -1;
```

Note:  It seems strange to use subqueries instead of `JOIN`s, but they should not affect performance.  However, the query will break if `LocalVariables` has more than one row.